# How can add the controls in application page easily

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

How to add controls to the application page in SharePoint 2010?

I am adding a application page in SharePoint 2010 and I want to add some controls to the application page, like asp.net I am not able drag and drop the controls directly in the design layout, Instead I have to work with the HTML code. This seems bit difficult to add and position the controls, is there any easy way to add & manage the controls? Can I do the drag and drop controls in SharePoint designer?

Can Somebody please help me quick

Tools: VSS 2010, SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

it is a visual studio limitation.

Application pages can be designed only in HTML view and not in Design view. Design view is disabled in VS. Hence you will not be able to add controls directly to the design view.

You can refer [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information

SharePoint Designer can be used for designing site pages and not for Farm level application pages.
Hope this helps.